# Processing like filtering ,distinct, transforming array of objects into sequence of objects and back to collection array of objects using RXJS only

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have alternative solution but it's more like use more non-rxjs function while removing duplicate, filtering  and transforming array of objects.

and this is impacting performance when there 150 to 500 records there.

Here is glimps of codes

**Typescript model**

```
export class columns {
    public displayName: string;
    public fieldName: string;
    public tabName: string;
    public tabOrder: string;
}
```

then behavior subject for transferring or listing array of columns from various part of application.

```
public columnsNotify: BehaviorSubject<columns[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

Some sample data

```
let listOfCols= [
    {displayName:"student name",fieldName:"stdName",tabName:"List",tabOrder:1},
    {displayName:"student id",fieldName:"stdid",tabName:"List",tabOrder:1},
    .....
    {displayName:"student name",fieldName:"stdName",tabName:"Details",tabOrder:2}
    {displayName:"student id",fieldName:"stdid",tabName:"Details",tabOrder:2}


];

this.columnsNotify.next(listOfCols);
```

Now the current solution, which I implemented for ***getting list of tabs with distinct and sorted by order***.

```
this.columnsNotify.pipe(
            map((column: columns[]) =>
                Array.from(
                    new Set(
                        column.map(mp => {
                            const obj = JSON.stringify({
                                tabName: mp.tabName,
                                tabOrder: mp.tabOrder
                            } as TabsInfo);

                            return obj;
                        })
                    )
                )
                    .map(data => JSON.parse(data))
                    .sort((a: TabsInfo, b: TabsInfo) => {
                        return a.tabOrder > b.tabOrder ? 1 : 0;
                    })
            )
        );
```

I tried to improve above code by flatting array but stuck at toArray operator as it wait for completion observable.

```
 this.columnsNotify.pipe(
        flatMap(searchCol => searchCol),
        map(
            (column: columns) =>
                new TabsInfo(column.tabName, column.tabOrder)
        ),
        distinct((tab: TabsInfo) => tab.tabName),
        take(3), //<-- Don't want this as, i don't know how many item there.
        toArray()  
    );
```

So, Is there anyway without using take operator with toArray, 
or it would be good whole different new approach.

I need similar solution at another place, where processed observable will be used in *ngFor, there also no luck so far n currently using different alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`toArray()` is your wanted operator but the problem for you lays here: `flatMap(searchCol => searchCol),`**

**This is your solution** to write something like this:

```
const expand = (items: columns[]) =>
  from(items).pipe(
    map((column: columns) => new TabsInfo(column.tabName, column.tabOrder)),
    distinct((tab: TabsInfo) => tab.tabName),
    toArray(),
  );

this.columnsNotify.pipe(
  switchMap((searchCol) => expand(searchCol)),
  tap((x) => console.log(x)),
);
```

Please use `switchMap()` operator which is in newer RxJS instead of `flatMap()`.
By the way `mergeMap()` is the new name for `flatMap()`, but in this case `switchMap()` is better.

If I understand correctly, tested it on numbers and works like you want.

Comment: This works perfect, but one thing I don't understand here How toArray knows observable is complete.

Comment: In your case Observable is not completing and `toArray()` is waiting for `complete()` signal, which is not happening. In this case, source Observable is switched to new expanded Observable which will get completed due to `from(items)`. As for explanation, `toArray()` is actually subscribing to Observable and stores all the emitted values in array and when source gets completed it emits resulted array.

Comment: Now I understood, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure why you can't just do it like this:

```
const obs$ = of(listOfCols);

obs$.pipe(
  flatMap(t => t),
  map(t => {return new TabsInfo(t.tabName, t.tabOrder)}),
  distinct((tab: TabsInfo) => tab.tabName),
  toArray(),
  map( array => array.sort())
  ).subscribe( // of course if you want to us it in *ngFor remove subscribe.
    t => console.log(t)
  )
```

I think i'm missing something.